# Learning Resources for Entity Framework 5

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5

My team is looking to shift asp.net form application from .NET 4 to .NET 4.5. We are hoping that we would be able to use the whole new Entity Framework 5. Being the in charge of this task I did look into the advantages of using EF5 and I am quite impressed.

EF5 gives you the ability to run **pre-compiled Queries** and that will be a great performance boost.

Apart from that we would be able to use enums and table-valued functions, that I am not very excited about but lets see how these can improve **Code Quality and maintenance.**

My Question is, are there any good resources that can help me learn some practical implication of EF5. I have been searching for some time and hope that there are people out there who have already jumped to EF5 and can post some useful resources in here.

Comment: This link seems interesting => http://devproconnections.com/entity-framework/improve-performance-entity-framework-5

Comment: If you are looking to invest in training material then Pluralsight has a good range of tutorials on EntityFramework as well as a lot of other ORMs and languages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not exactly about EF but for "MVC with EF".
I'm learning MVC these days & I've learned quite a bit. I would like to share my experience and how the whole training can be highly effective. If you go systematic, everything is simple and cool. I would advise you to first cover some basic concepts which are used in MVC and entity framework:

1. Extension Types
2. Lambda Expression
3. LINQ
4. Anonymous Types

You can find good information on these at  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FejRZ6QYWHw.
If you already know that you can skip.

Next you can start learning the EF. You can do so by following Lynda Tutorials which I found to be extremely simple and effective (avoid Plurasight as of now).

You can also visit asp.net website and check the Getting started with EF6 using MVC 5. It has wonderful list of articles, which I would recommend to everyone.

And once you are done with that, you should be capable enough to build any web application. If you want more higher level details you can then opt for Plurasight tutorials.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering my question. I was strictly looking for turotials with web forms. Do you know any good place where I can find web forms tutorials with EF5